# dojox/form/Uploader additional parameters

Tags: dojo, uploader

I would like to use dojox/form/Uploader and post some additional data to upload url.
I tried to use submit() method to submit the form in which upload lays, I set uploader uploadOnSelect: false but was not able to catch the file choose event to trigger the submit() function. 
My html looks like this:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="something" >
<div id="uploader"></div>
</form>
```

And my upload js looks like this:

```
require(['dojox/form/Uploader',"dojo/dom",
         "dojox/form/uploader/plugins/IFrame",
         "dojo/domReady!"], function(Uploader, dom){

  myUploader = new Uploader({
    label: "Select files",
    multiple: false,
    uploadOnSelect: false,
    url: "UploadFile"
  }, "uploader");

 myUploader.startup();


});
```

Where should I put the myUploader.submit(); function for uploader to submit on file choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
// [...]

myUploader.on('change', function(){
    uploader.submit(dom.byId("myform"));
});

myUploader.startup();
```

Comment: Is it the only way to add extra parameters (for example, if I still want to use uploadOnSelect)?

Comment: This example is not showing how to add parameters, it's showing how to connect to the uploader's onChange 'event'. Parameters are set the way shown in the question, by passing a javascript object to the constructor of the Uploader as the first parameter.